# Componente HTML processador de texto

Tags: html, wysiwyg

Preciso converter a seguinte tela feita em *Silverlight* para *HTML*, mas o maior desafio está no componente abaixo semelhante a um processador de texto como o Word. Existe algum componente gratuito para substituí-lo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O termo usado para se referir a este tipo de editor é *WYSIWYG*, acrônimo da expressão em inglês *"What You See Is What You Get"*, remete a algo como "O que você vê é o que você terá".

Existem vários *WYSIWYG*, como:

- SummerNote: https://summernote.org
- QuillJS: https://quilljs.com
- TinyMCE: https://www.tinymce.com
- CkEditor: https://ckeditor.com
- Fckeditor: https://www.drupal.org/project/fckeditor
- Froola editor: https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor
- FreeTextBox: http://www.freetextbox.com (pra asp.net)
- Niceedit: http://nicedit.com
- SCEEditor: https://www.sceditor.com

Fica a sua escolha qual é o melhor pra ti.